# What are the best technologies for an online payment website

Tags: payment-gateway

I'm going to build a business website which is having the online payment option with it. I'm familiar with PHP and Symfony framework. Is Symfony is suitable for this kind of simple web sites.

But I'm not sure what technology is suitable for a this kind of website. Since the security of this site should be high I'm planning to use a framework for this site.

I need some additional features such as file uploading for this site. What are the best technologies for developing this site.

Please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is more about techniques than "technologies".

Comment: @musefan What is that. ?

Comment: @Diodeus I need to know about the suitable technologies for this. Is there anything wrong with that.

Comment: Obviously SSL + whatever server-side language you like. No magic here.

Answer (score 1):

A professional website for payment transactions (like LR/PAYPAL, etc ?) should in my opinion not use ANY public framework. Same goes for any "high security" website you plan.
Mainly because there are thousands of people private and in public that search those frameworks for bugs.
That's why I'd develop something, in a secure way, from ground up to add an obfusaction layer.

If you want to use PHP then use a [hardened version](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) of it.
If you use a linux webserver make sure you have a proper setup [iptables firewall](http://www.netfilter.org/) on it to close anything not required.
An [IDS](http://www.snort.org/) can help detect successfull and attempted penetrations.